# Is there an option type for only Voice Channels in discord_slash?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Is there an option type for only Voice Channels in [discord_slash](https://pypi.org/project/discord-py-slash-command/), similar to the following?
[image: this]

Comment: I have no experience with discord_slash, so take this with a grain of salt, but can you use the `VoiceChannelConverter` from the base discord.py library? https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=converter#discord.ext.commands.VoiceChannelConverter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I don’t have any experience with `discord.py-interactions` in particular (the library of `discord-slash`, renamed from `discord-py-slash-command`), but I’ve done some research and testing on this library. Here’s my findings:

Is it possible to specify only voice channels through Discord API? Yes definitely. But not natively with discord-slash. You’ll need to apply the following workaround:

```
only_vc_option = create_option(
    name="choice",
    description="You can only choose a VC!",
    option_type=SlashCommandOptionType.CHANNEL,
    required=True
)
only_vc_option['channel_types'] = [2]


@slash.slash(name="test",
             description="This is just a test command.",
             options=[only_vc_option])
async def test(ctx, choice: discord.VoiceChannel):
    await ctx.send(content=f"You chose {choice}, which is a {type(choice)}!")
```

discord-slash doesn't have any support to specify the channel type explicitly, but it also doesn't sanitize the options dict that gets passed to Discord API. Therefore, it is possible to create the option as usual, then add the `channel_types` key and set it to a list of only `2` (voice channel type). And when you type-hint `discord.VoiceChannel`, discord.py does the proper channel conversion for you.

As a footnote, `discord.py-interactions` isn't well maintained nor documented, perhaps try out some other active libraries such as `disnake` which is `discord.py` combined with `dislash`. (I have no affiliations, just a recommendation)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>No. The [official Discord docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/application-commands#application-command-object-application-command-option-type) show that the only type you can use is `CHANNEL` (value `7`), and it</strike>

> Includes all channel types + categories

EDIT: I'm blind, use `channel_types`

> channel_types? - array of channel types: if the option is a channel type, the channels shown will be restricted to these types

https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#channel-object-channel-types

Comment: Then, how did the bot in the image manage to do it?

Comment: As you can see in the image, it only showed the voice channels and omitted text channels.

Comment: *I've edited my answer

Comment: So, what should I enter for the `option_type` argument?

Comment: I don't see `option_type` anywhere at first glance, only `type`. That should still be `CHANNEL` (`7`) as you still want the type of that argument to be a channel. `channel_type` is something that you add when the type is already `CHANNEL`, as my quote from the docs says.

Comment: I am talking about the [discord-py-slash-command](https://pypi.org/project/discord-py-slash-command/) library.